# How are the results of a fourier-transform interpolated to cover the entire frequency range?

Tags: fourier-transform, audio, interpolation, audio-processing

Say we have an audio signal and we do a Fourier transform with block size 2048. Now the outputs correspond to 1024 different frequencies. A spectrum analyzer however doesn't just display 1024 discrete lines, but instead show a value for every frequency (example below).

Most spectrum analyzers seem to do that in the exact same way (at least they all look very similar), so is there a sort of default way to interpolate the amplitude of frequencies outside of those 1024 specific frequencies?

[image: Example of a continuous spectrum analyzer]

Comment: Are you asking about how are more sample points computed, or how they are displayed?

Comment: "but instead show a value for every frequency" Not exactly. You can't show more frequencies than you have pixels. For a linear frequency display the number of pixels and FFT size are actually quite similar. However, for a log frequency axis, interpolation is indeed helpful

Comment: I'd be very careful with the advice that zero-padding the time domain data and FFTing that will solve your problem.  Remember that your frequency scale is ***log*** frequency.  And what comes out of the FFT is ***linear*** frequency. You will still have to use continuous-frequency interpolation in the bottom octave because the FFT points will be too widely spaced.

Answer (score 4):

This is coming from an audio developer (me):

Most FFT analyzers in audio plugins are actually very simple. From the 1024-4096 frequency bins that are usually output by the FFT a 2D Path is created. Most GUI-Libraries have a class for that, which includes lines, splines and other primitives. So just connect each bin by a straight line, usually with log-spacing for the Amplitude and Frequency axis and your done. This would already give a pretty good result.

If you want to make it look nicer, most 2D Path classes have a way to transform a path into the same path, but with rounded corners. This achieves a very close result to the picture shown.

Other tricks include:

- Average multiple FFTs (Analyzer moves/decays slower)
- Don't use all the bins (high frequencies are to dense to be useful)

Comment: Approval from another audio developer.  I think the zero-padding answers missed the big issue that spectrum analyzer is log-frequency.  I might suggest, instead of linear interpolation between FFT points (chosen as exponentially spaced in frequency), I would suggest 3rd-order Hermite (or Catmull-Rom) spline.  That preserves continuity in both 0th and 1st derivatives.  Linear only does that with the 0th derivative.

Answer (score 1):

I think most audio spectrum analyzers will display the spectrum with log gain (in dB) vs. log frequency. This is shown in the figure in the OP. The output of the FFT will be very dense in higher octaves but far less dense at lower frequencies.  That's where interpolation is most needed.

Dunno what most manufacturers do but off the cuff I might use cubic splines maybe.  Like [Hermite polynomial or Catmull-Rom splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Interpolation_on_the_unit_interval_with_matched_derivatives_at_endpoints).

So, if your spectrum image update rate is reasonably slow, like you only need to update 10 frames per second, that leaves plenty time for a good long FFT.  Instead of 1K or even 4096-point FFT, let's do a 64K (65536) FFT.

Now, this window of 65536 samples is probably much longer than you need, but we'll make use of that.  Other answers suggested zero-padding (which will make your FFT longer), but I have a better idea (from experience).  You really should window the sampled data, even if you were to zero-pad.  In fact, not windowing the data (and zero-padding) is exactly the rectangular window, which is about the worst window.

There are better windows, but all of them, except a very few (maybe just one, in theory) causes spectral leakage that appear as ripples and these ripples might be confused with frequency components.  The viewer might incorrectly conclude that some small bump is a frequency component that really doesn't exist.  Or, a ripple due to windowing might obscure a small frequency component that really is there.

The Gaussian window has a Fourier Transform that is another Gaussian function in the frequency domain.  It's a special function.  Now, in reality, a Gaussian window never really gets to zero, so to make it finite in length, you have to truncate it to zero and that truncated Gaussian window will have tiny ripples.  ***But***, if your FFT is long, you can let your Gaussian get down to a very small value, like $10^{-9}$ or $10^{-10}$ or something very close to zero, before truncating.  Then numerically, there is little difference between the untruncated Gaussian and the truncated Gaussian and your ripples will also be about $10^{-9}$ of the size of the main lobe.  This is essentially what you do instead of zero-padding.  The Gaussian window will be soooooo close to zero for most of those 65536 samples that it has the effect of zero padding.

Because your FFT is so long (say more than a second, if your sample rate is 48 kHz) that the part of the Gaussian window that is more than $\frac12$ or $\frac14$ is still several thousand samples wide.  So you'll have good frequency resolution ***and*** there are no bumps of any size that are not due to **real** frequency components.  The ripples are just too small to be significant.

Now, the output of your FFT is in linear frequency, not log frequency, so you'll be sampling that linear spectrum with an exponentially-spaced samples.  One sample for each pixel-width in your displayed spectrum.  But these samples might not line up on exactly integer bin values.  At high frequencies simply rounding to the nearest neighbor would be sufficient, but not at low frequencies.  So you may as well interpolate between each FFT value, whether they are high frequency or low, just to be consistent.

Linear interpolation is not terribly bad, and would be fine at high frequencies, but might look *not smooth*.  So I would recommend that 3rd-order Hermite or Catmull-Rom spline applied to the linear-frequency FFT data above.  Then **after** sampling the cubic-interpolate magnitude-squared, **then** apply the $\log(\cdot)$ function to convert to dB.  Now you have a log-log set of data that is ready to draw on your display.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, zero pad the time domain waveform out to the total number of frequencies you would like to plot and compute the DFT for that zero-padded waveform. This will interpolate new values in between the values that would have been given with the original DFT. This does not provide any new information, just shows you what is already there as more samples on the Discrete Time Fourier Transform (DTFT, which is a continuous function in the frequency domain). The result of zero padding in the time domain is the same as convolving the samples in frequency with samples of the Dirichlet Kernel. As you increase the number of samples in the DFT, the Dirichlet Kernel approaches a Sinc function, and convolving with a Sinc provides perfect interpolation.